# Is spectral decomposition a differentiable function?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Given a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix $A$, we can write it as: $A=U\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)U^T$.
So the spectral decomposition of $A$ is a function of that maps $A$
to $U(A)$ and the eigenvalues of $A$. Is U(A) differentiable in $A$?

Comment: Usually we talk about differentiating maps wrt their domain. Do you mean to ask whether it's differentiable in $A$? (Which I suppose would mean differentiable in each matrix entry $A_{ij}$.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I fixed the question. I wonder if U(A) is differentiable in A?

Comment: $U$ is discontinuous at $A = I$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea: near a point (matrix) $A_0$ with $n$ different eigenvalues, apply the implicit function theorem to the equation
$$\det(A - \lambda I) = 0.$$